# GCC generate assembly language output with make file

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am trying to generate, and save to a file, the assembly language for a program that is compiled using a configure file.

I want to generate the same sort out output that -S produces but unfortunately this does not work because no output object is generated. The general compile goes like:

```
make clean
make distclean
CFLAGS="-O1" ./configure --prefix="a/location/"
CFLAGS="-O1" make
make install
```

When the CFLAGS also contains "-Wa,-a,-ad,-aln=assembly.lst" it generates this for the output file:

```
   1                    .file   "conftest.c"
   2                    .text
   3                .globl main
   5                main:
   6                .LFB4:
   7                    .cfi_startproc
   8 0000 B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
   8      00
   9 0005 C3            ret
  10                    .cfi_endproc
  11                .LFE4:
  13                    .comm   x,4,4
  14                    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.6"
  15                    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
DEFINED SYMBOLS
                            *ABS*:0000000000000000 conftest.c
     /tmp/cc8eyzpq.s:5      .text:0000000000000000 main
                            *COM*:0000000000000004 x
```

I would expect a lot more to be generated, or perhaps I am misunderstanding what the flags do. Again my aim is to generate all the optimised code as assembly language similar to the -S option.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking at is the assembly code of a test run during `configure`. You might also try `CFLAGS=-save-temps`.

Comment: @Jester how would I get the proper assembly code from the real program then rather than the test run? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `configure` picks up the `CFLAGS` for the actual build, just adding `-save-temps` should work.

Comment: @Jester im afraid I just get the same output with that, the assembly.lst contains the same information as displayed above

Comment: Do not use the `-aln=assembly.lst` and look for generated output files with extension `.s` (should be beside all the sources).